# Python objects sharing instance variable list

Tags: python, list, memory-address

I have a class `Bin` that contains a list `items` as an instance variable. I need to create a list of `Bin` objects and then add data to their `items` lists. For some reason, all the `Bin`s seem to be sharing the same `items` list, even though `items` is (AFAIK) not static. What's going on?

MWE:

```
import numpy as np

class Bin:

    def __init__(self, items=[], left_edge=None, right_edge=None):
        self.items = items
        self.left_edge = left_edge
        self.right_edge = right_edge

    def add(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

# Create data
mean = 10.0
stdev = 2.0
sampsize = 10
data = np.random.normal(mean, stdev, sampsize)

# Create bins
bin_width = 0.5
bin_edges = np.arange(min(data), max(data) + bin_width, bin_width)

bins = []
print 'Before data add:'
for i in range(bin_edges.size-1):
    bins.append(Bin(left_edge=bin_edges[i], right_edge=bin_edges[i+1]))
    print id(bins[i].items)

# Actually put data in bins
indices = np.digitize(data, bin_edges[0:-1:1]) # need to cut off right edge
data_and_indices = np.array([data, indices]).T

print 'After data add:'
for pair in data_and_indices:
    point = pair[0]
    index = pair[1]
    bins[int(index-1)].add(point)
    print id(bins[int(index-1)].items)
    print bins[int(index-1)].items
```

Comment: Duplicate indeed. I never would have looked for that title.